# Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I got the following Error in android Studio 2.2.3 when I sync gradle.

**Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

How can I fix this issue

I am Adding my Gradle file also

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
} } dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// FireBase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}//Add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and the project Level Gradle File

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I had this issue before, It go somehow solved by properly exiting the application, restarting pc, and then open app and rebuild graddle. Something to with local cache issue. app i mean android studio.

Comment: @Smit I tried that also but not fixed yet

Comment: Can you share you gradle code

Comment: @Smit aded the Gradle code in the question

Comment: Are you working in your house or in a company building?

Comment: @Bisonfan95 Company

Comment: Must be that, I have Gradle issues too when I try to build my project from a company network. The most probable cause is a proxy wall.

Comment: try adding this lines to your gradle.properties file and complete them with the respective credentials

systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=
systemProp.http.proxyUser=
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=

Comment: @Bisonfan95 Added these already but couldnt resolved the issue

Comment: post your project level build.gradle.

Comment: @Ahamed Added the Project level build.gradle

Comment: please do invalid cache it will solve your problem

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This problem might be due to some restricted internet connections...
If you are installing build tools on some restricted network, the required certificates might not install... So try changing the network connection....
Worked for me.....

Comment: Worked for me....
Earlier, I was working on my University network but I changed to my smartphone network, it worked for me.

Comment: Yep this did it for me too. I was on a corporate network and when I switched it worked.

Comment: Had the same issue, turns out I had proxy turned on. Disabled it and it worked.

Comment: or disable a sort of web proxy and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62836938/4770877

Comment: Restart Charles Proxy and disable proxying, ssl and recording

Comment: I had my VPN on... that was my issue, I turned it off and now it's working

Answer (score 74):

I faced the same issue, but fixed it by adding

```
maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
```

in the **project Level Gradle File**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: ok but _why_ did this work? whats happening here thats causing this issue?

Comment: Mine was an issue with McAffee. I had to disable it before gradle would sync properly.

Answer (score 43):

***"Unable to find valid certification path to requested target"***

If you are getting this message, you probably are behind a Proxy on your company, which probably is signing all request certificates with your company root CA certificate, this certificate is trusted only inside your company, so Android Studio cannot validate any certificate signed with your company certificate as valid, so, you need to tell Android Studio to trust your company certificate, you do that by adding your company certificate to Android Studio truststore.

*(I'm doing this on macOS, but should be similar on Linux or Windows)*

- First, you need to save your company root CA certificate as a file: you can ask this certificate to your IT department, or download it yourself, here is how. Open your browser and open this url, for example, https://jcenter.bintray.com/ or https://search.maven.org/, click on the ***lock*** icon and then click on ***Show certificate***

[image]

On the popup window, to save the root certificate as a file, make sure to select the top level of the certificates chain (the root cert) and drag the certificate image to a folder/directory on your disk drive. It should be saved as a file as, for example: *my-root-ca-cert.cer*, or *my-root-ca-cert.pem*

[image]

- Second, let's add this certificate to the accepted Server Certificates of Android Studio:

On Android Studio open `Preferences -> Tools -> Server Certificates`,
on the box `Accepted certificates` click the plus icon (`+`), search the certificate you saved previously and click `Apply` and `OK`

[image]

- Third, you need to add the certificate to the Android Studio JDK truststore (Gradle use this JDK to build the project, so it's important):

In Android Studio open `File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location`

[image]

Copy the path of JDK Location, and open the Terminal, and change your directory to that path, for example, execute:

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/
```

(don't forget to scape the whitespace, "\ ")

Now, to import the certificate to the truststore, execute:

```
./bin/keytool -importcert -file /path/to/your/certificate/my-root-ca-cert.cer -keystore ./jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

- Finally, restart Android Studio, or better click `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Done, you should be able to build your project now.

Comment: Broken images didn't help any, but this answer DID fix my problem.  I initially skipped the last step, which is what I truly needed.

Comment: in case you use jdk 11 this: ./jre/lib/security/cacerts should be: ./lib/security/cacerts

Comment: that last step really made myday. Thanks, buddy

Comment: Good explanation and even better solution that works even in 2023. Thanks a lot! FYI, if anybody's using Android Studio Preview versions like me, the path to keystore is then: 

lib/security/cacerts

Comment: you can get your cacerts path in windows by using "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts"

Answer (score 14):

I have faced this problem with Maven build earlier. It was occurring because I was working in a restricted office network. You need to import required certificate in your keystore.

Follow Steps in the answer of below question
["unable to find valid certification path to requested target", but browser says it's OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180650/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-but-browser-says)

(use double quotes for fienames/pathnames)

Note: I am not able to find now exact source from where I solved problem, if I get it, I will update it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180650/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-but-browser-says?answertab=votes#tab-top worked for me

Comment: for Intellij Idea: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000094584-IDEA-Ultimate-2016-3-4-throwing-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-when-trying-to-refresh-gradle

Comment: I tried adding certificate also but that didn't helped.

Answer (score 13):

Import your company certificate at Tools->Android->SDK Manager->Tools->Server Certificates

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, just make sure to restart IntelliJ after setting the cert.

Comment: I added certificate from https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter. Restart studio and build was successful.

Comment: @IfOnly Can you link to where to get the cert for jcenter?

Answer (score 8):

I just encountered the similar problem and found a series of steps did help me.
Of course few of them is to Change the network to a stronger,better one.or if you have only one network then try Reconnecting to the network and then simply INVALIDATE/RESTART your android studio.
If it still shows the error you need to add the "maven" in repositories and point it out to the link as shown below:
maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}

Finally,Go to 
 *File
   *Settings
     *Build,Execution and deployment
       *Gradle
        *Android Studio
       --------And check Enable maven repository option.

After that simply clean and rebuild your APP and you will be good to go.

Comment: The setting `Android Studio` > `Enabled embeded marvin repository` seems to finally make things work. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you are running behind a corporate proxy with SSL interception, you will need to follow these steps to trust your proxy certificate for HTTPS:

- In Android Studio, Open File -> Settings

  - In Tools -> Server Certificates

    - Tick ‘Accept non-trusted certificates automatically’
    - Also click the ‘+’ and manually add the corporate proxy root certificate.
  - In Appearance and Behaviour -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy

    - Set your corporate proxy URL and port details
- Download KeyStore Explorer: http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html
- In KeyStore Explorer (run as admin), open the Android Studio JRE certificate store: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\security\cacerts

  - The password should be ‘changeit’
  - Import the corporate proxy root certificate, and save.
- In Android Studio, select File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart

Comment: Thanks man, it solved my problem, this was exactly the problem I was experiencing, due to internal proxy restrictions.

Answer (score 7):

If you re in your office ,use your smartphone network. I think It will work.

Comment: This saved my day.

Comment: This is NOT a solution

Comment: it worked for me ,cause my company network have more security

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by removing/commenting proxy settings in gradle.properties. Check your gradle.properties, if you have some like this

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyHost=192.168.1.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=192.168.1.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

comment it with #. Which will look like this

```
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=192.168.1.1
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=192.168.1.1
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

Comment: Or just remove entirely.

Comment: @Zoe yes, we can but what if we need in the future? Better option is comment.

Comment: This solved my problem - I mean removing the https proxy!

Answer (score 3):

I  missed this problem after update studio and gradle ,in the log file tips me some maven store has certificate problem.

I tried restart statudio as somebody suggestion but dose work;
and somebody said we should set the jre environment ,but I doesn't know how to set it on Mac .
So I tried restart Mac. and start studio I found this tips.[image]

so the problem is floating on the surface:
solution:
first step: restart computer ,there are too many problem after android studio update .
second step:use the old gradle tool **OR** download the *pom and jar ,put in correct folder.

Comment: I missed the same problem  when my colleague update studio but I haven't update . Then I update studio ，but the problem occurs again . **I tried a lot of solution until this solved my problem. **.    My computer is Mac.

Comment: I missed the same problem again, all the solution description above doesn't work, then I closed Charles and restart studio , it's ok .

Answer (score 2):

Part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63235324/4833705) by @Sadegh is what fixed it for me

Go to `Gradle Scripts` > `gradle.properties`

Enter these 6 lines in the `gradle.properties` file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
```

[image]

To dig deeper into the issue, I went inside Android Studio (not your mac), at the bottom I opened Terminal and entered: `./gradlew build --warning-mode all`

The exact problem was:

> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 1):

You are using older version of libraries.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
```

Comment: Update the gradle in the configuration and the error.

Comment: Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. This error I got when the gradle Sync

Answer (score 1):

Like a noob!

I was getting a nightmare with this and forgot that i've recently installed a new AV (Kaspersky)

So another solution is: Disable your AV or add exclusions to your AV firewall or proxy

hope it helps to save some time.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are **using kotlin** and its showing this error please update your kotlin gradle plugin in project level build.gradle.
2. The **certificate expired** case : Go to certificates in settings and check if any certificate is expired if any, delete that certificate and clean and sync it will work.
3. **Dependencies- unable to find case** : In this case delete that dependency and sync the project then add the dependency again with some another version(downgraded version) and sync the project it will work.

These three cases i faced and wasted so much time, hope this will help someone and save someones day.

Thankyou - happy coding**:-)**

Answer (score 1):

Run bellow command in Android studio terminal after opening the same project. It worked for me.

**On Windows:**

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

**On Mac or Linux:**

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Comment: This worked for me. thank you so much! I first followed Minion point-2 and then your command.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to build the same project through command prompt and if the download dependencies happen successfully, go to settings in you IntelliJ and map the gradle to point gradle in your system and build should happen fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error is is because of your network restriction that does not allow to sync the project from "http://jcenter.bintray.com", No need play with the IDE (Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

change dependencies from compile to Implementation in build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Switching to the smartphone network & disabling the web security tool installed on my computer solved the problem.

Comment: This is a local solution, as there are people working in companies where they cannot disable security tool installed on their computer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to network connectivity if not solved adding maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"} at project level.

Just try to change your network and sync the gradle, should fix this issue for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue  and I fixed it by changing my firewall setting or you can switch to another network

**reasons behind it**

when we are running our project run command its configure and check for exiting packages and make proceed to download the new or required  package and the packages are stored on non-secure IP/hosting so  your firewall will try to protect you and you will get these errors

Answer (score 0):

Those who tried all the above answers and didn't help, or lazy to follow those steps, should try this quick-setting first.

- Go to **Android Studio** -> **Appearance & Behavior** -> **System Settings** -> **HTTP Proxy** -> Select **Auto-detect proxy settings**
- Go to **Android Studio** -> **File** -> **Sync Project with Gradle File**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was caused by the Proxyman/Charles proxy tool. I fixed this by closing Proxyman, resetting the Android Studio cache and restarting the emulator. After that everything started working

Answer (score -2):

Most of the times when I face this issue. I remove replace `https` with `http`. It solves the issue.

Comment: Insecure connections aren't a good idea when you have options

Comment: I agree, But the firewall setting is taken care by the IT department, which I have no control on. What would u suggest as an alternative?

Comment: Contacting the IT department and telling them to create/use a firewall that doesn't block basic dev tools

Answer (score -2):

Simple Invalidate/Restart fixed it for me. No other actions were taken