# Not able to build Android Studio for First time

Tags: android, gradle

Getting error when trying build for first time in Android

```
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project


4:41 PM Gradle sync started

4:41 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1s 129ms)
```

Able to do network connection Ok .But still this error is present.

@Gautam Surani Can't find the check box to offine

[image]

[image]

@Prasad Bonthu I think proxy settings is fine.

[image]

[image]

Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Also getting

Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.2.3/gradle-core-2.2.3.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

After changing  maven { url "jcenter.bintray.com"; }

can anybody pls share any vaild project for Android Studio 3.1.3 Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 7 6.1

[image]

Not able to add module

Comment: Are you access the network through a proxy server?

Comment: @PrasadBonthu Yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go file>setting>Build,Execution,Deployment> Gradle >Android Studio
and Enable embededded Maven repository

Answer (score 1):

Try to set offline mode

1. Click File => Settings (on a Mac, Android Studio => Preferences) to
       open the Settings dialog.
2. In the left pane, expand Build, Execution, Deployment and then
       click Gradle.
3. Under Global Gradle settings, check the Offline work checkbox.

Comment: Not able to find Offline work checkbox attached picture in question

Comment: Getting No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415666/errorcause-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415666/errorcause-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target)

Comment: now getting Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.2.3/gradle-core-2.2.3.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: can you pls share any vaild project for Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1

Comment: Your proxy needs authentication and the authentication you supply is invalid or your proxy does not allow to request that URL with the authentication details you supply.

Answer (score 1):

Try

**File -> Invalidate Chache/ Restart -> Click on Invalidate and Restart**

I hope it should work.

Comment: Now getting Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: Disable gradle offline mode.

Comment: getting now failed -Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: remove jcenter() from build.gradle  and add following  in repositories   
        repositories {
                  maven {
                          url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"
                          }
        }

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir}

Comment: remove Jcenter() and add maven { url "jcenter.bintray.com"; } into repositories

Comment: added  { google() maven { url "jcenter.bintray.com";} }

Comment: getting Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 1):

For me I had a problem with one particular application in Android Studio 2021.2.1 (Chipmunk) in Windows 7. So I went to File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle and changed the Gradle JDK from JRE version 8 to 11. This resolved the issue. And did the invalidate cache before doing this and did a clean and build after that.

[image]