# Gradle sync failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just install android studio 3.1.3,because of certification issue i just downgrade the studio to 3.0.1 version, even though am getting the certification issue.,The issue comes when I try to creating a project am getting the certification issue like that **"Gradle sync failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"**

I didn't understand what cause for the issue.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
   jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415666/errorcause-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target)

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection. This happened to me when I was connected to corporate restricted internet.

Connect to a non-restricted internet solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a antivirus or something like that, try to turn off and build your project.

I had this problem, and occurs that was my kaspersky internet security blocking the communication.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
```

Comment: This should be avoided. Adding `+` as the dependency version risks updating it at a random time, and breaking it in a hard to diagnose way.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your valuable comment.