# " unable to find valid certification path to requested target" android studio

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I have been struggling with this error for a long time and still could not find a solution to it. I have installed android studio 4 on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. I am connected to the internet behind a proxy. I googgled it and set the configuration, but with no luck.

Any help is appricated. Find below the error exception.

Thank you in advance.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'RALAPP5'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'RALAPP5'.
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
  at
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 876ms

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: suddenly I found the solution here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997483/5120201