# unable to find valid certification path to requested target - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I created a new Application in Flutter. I try to run that application on Android Mobile. It shows below Error.

```
  "Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445)
... 26 more
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"
```

But when I tried to run the same in Chrome or Edge(Web Device). It is running.

Comment: make sure build gradle is successful. use a vpn to build gradle if necessary.

Comment: Gradle is not running Benyamin. While running only it showing an error.

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415666/errorcause-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown when you're trying to run an Android build is because the artifacts required for the Android gradle plugin is unreachable. [JCenter](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) no longer receives updates, and it's recommended to update the repository referenced in the project-level build.gradle to `mavenCentral()` to be able to download the updated certificates.

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```