# Android Studio: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, app-certification-kit

while I was creating a new project Gradle Project Sync Failed, it shows :
Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
but
running my older project it runs perfectly. No, any error
I didn't find the solution for the error anywhere. Help me out

build.gradle(:) -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

app/build.gradle -

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.myapplication"
        minSdk 16
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

PLEASE HELP ME ANYONE :)

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem as you, I managed to solve it like this: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/63469344/6565223