# Getting unable to find valid certification path. But the URL is working in browser in the same machine

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, certificate

I am trying to add Taboola sdk

Project build.gradle

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://taboolapublic.jfrog.io/artifactory/mobile-release' }
    ...
}
```

app build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.taboola:android-sdk:3.8.15'
```

I am getting the below Errors

```
Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Detailed Error

```
> Could not resolve com.taboola:android-sdk:3.8.15.
     > Could not get resource 'https://taboolapublic.jfrog.io/artifactory/mobile-release/com/taboola/android-sdk/3.8.15/android-sdk-3.8.15.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://taboolapublic.jfrog.io/artifactory/mobile-release/com/taboola/android-sdk/3.8.15/android-sdk-3.8.15.pom'.
           > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
              > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

But I am able to access this link the same machines browser
https://taboolapublic.jfrog.io/artifactory/mobile-release/com/taboola/android-sdk/3.8.15/android-sdk-3.8.15.pom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415666/errorcause-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target)

Comment: @ChinHuang If it was network restriction then it should not hit the url in browser as well, right? But it is working in browser but not in android studio