# Adding Lottie Library into Android Studio Project gives me this : "Unable to resolve dependency for"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add Lottie library into my Android Project using this line :

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0'
```

& after syncing it shows this errors :

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0.
```

I've tried adding other Lottie versions as well but still showing the same errors. I'm using Android Studio 3.2 & Target SDK is 28.
Please help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have `jcenter()` or similar included in the `repositories` block in your app's build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes I do have both  `google()  jcenter()` in repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Plain 2.5 version doesn't seem to exist (as per their [Github repo](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/releases?after=v2.6.0-beta2))

Use 2.7 instead :

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
```

Comment: I've just tried 2.7.0 as per your suggestion but still giving me exact same errors.

Comment: I tried it on one of my projects, and it worked. Have you checked you are not [offline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487979/7540393) ?

Comment: There is a 2.5.0: https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.airbnb.android%3Alottie.

Comment: Ok. Yes I've checked. Offline is unchecked under gradle section  I'm also connected to working internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

This (could not resolve error) only occurs when you are missing files or components related to specific implementation dependency
Make sure to add json file as well in the res folder...
app-->res then right click and new--->folder-->assets folder and paste it..

Answer (score 0):

Use 3.0.0 and you will be good to go.
Happy coding

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.0'
}
```