# What does >Could not find android.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0. mean in Android Studio and how can I solve this

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im quite new to Android studio so any help will be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file so we can see what it contains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218535/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.